# Android Error: Undefined Method

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've got a Fragment (ActionBarSherlock Tabs), and I want to run a Chronometer in Background:

```
public class BFragment extends SherlockFragment {

private Button start;
private View v;
private Chronometer chrono;
private Button pause;
private Button reset;
private long lastPause;
private Button resume;
private boolean isChronometerRunning = false;
private boolean richtig = false;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_bfragment, container, false);
    start = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.start); 
    chrono = (Chronometer) v.findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
    pause = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.pause);
    reset = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.reset);
    resume = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.resume);


    new ChronoBackground().execute();


    return v;

}

void StartTimer() {
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            chrono.start();
            isChronometerRunning = true;
            System.out.println(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

        }
    });

    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            lastPause = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            chrono.stop();
            isChronometerRunning = false;
            richtig = true;

        }
    });

    resume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (isChronometerRunning == false && richtig) {
                chrono.setBase(chrono.getBase() + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastPause);
                chrono.start();
                richtig = false;
            } else {

            }
        }
    });

    reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            System.out.println(chrono.getBase());

        }
    });
}
}
```

And here is my ChronBackground class/code:

```
public class ChronoBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

/** The system calls this to perform work in a worker thread and
  * delivers it the parameters given to AsyncTask.execute() */

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    StartTimer();
    return null;
}

/** The system calls this to perform work in the UI thread and delivers
  * the result from doInBackground() */
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    return ;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

        return ;
}
}
```

Now there's an error, and I'm not really sure if my chrono is working this way... The error is at ChronoBackground: StartTimer() not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is perhaps in the fact, that ChronoBackground is not an innerclass of BFragment and doesn't see the method?

Comment: Ok, I changed public class ChronoBackground to private class ChronoBackground and moved it into my BFragment... But when I start my application and change the view or change the tab the timer resets to 00:00 altough it should run in background - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: OK, that is another question, though! You need to make timer a `Service`, to make it running in the background. AsyncTask is for two threads - GUI and "logic", but you need a thread "behind the logic" and that is exactly what Service does. Search for it here, it is around. Make sure you mark answer right if you used it also ;)